# How to get multiple values from one function contract to another

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, remix

I have two contract and in first contract it contains a function which is responsible for returning two values, one of string and one of integer.

```
function getUserData(address userAddress)
    public    constant    returns(string, uint)
  {
    string Firstname = "Hello";
    uint number=123;
   return( Firstname,number);
  }
```

On compiling this gives error
**"Type literal_string "Hello" is not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage pointer.
    string Firstname = "Hello";
"**
In the second contract I make object of first contract and tried to get function

```
function FetchDetail(address userAddress) public constant returns(string,uint )
  {
    string memory  data1;
    uint  data2;
    UserRegistration ud=new UserRegistration();
   (data1,data2)= ud.getUserData(userAddress);
    return(data1,data2);
  }
```

But I am unable to get values. Please suggest me.

Comment: The compilation error can be resolved with `string memory Firstname = "Hello";`.

Answer (score 3):

Since `Firstname` is a string literal defined in the function scope, missing to explicitly define the data location sets it to `storage` by default (where the state variables are persisted) [1]. That assignment operation then looks for the data at the provided location, which in the example is not a valid `storage` reference.
In order to solve the compilation error in the provided example, it is necessary to set the `memory` keyword, as pointed out by user *smarx*: `string memory Firstname = "Hello";`.

The second snippet is valid, as of *Solidity* version `0.4.25`.

Given the provided code snippets, the following would be the aggregated code, to serve as reference (`SecondContract.sol`):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract UserRegistration {
    function getUserData(address userAddress) public constant returns(string, uint) {
        string memory Firstname = "Hello";
        uint number=123;
        return( Firstname,number);
    }
}

contract SecondContract {
    function FetchDetail(address userAddress) public constant returns(string,uint ) {
        string memory  data1;
        uint  data2;
        UserRegistration ud=new UserRegistration();
        (data1,data2)= ud.getUserData(userAddress);
        return(data1,data2);
    }
}
```

Deploying `SecondContract` and calling `FetchDetail` function with `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` as argument returns:

`string Hello
uint256 123`

[1] https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/types.html#data-location

Stay super!

/Javi